# POST JSON Data to web API in SSIS Script task from SQL

Tags: c#, json, api, ssis

I have been searching for an answer to this question, but I keep coming up short so hopefully I can find an answer. Admittedly I am not the best C# programmer and this is born out of necessity and not having a resource to help develop this for me, so I have jumped in feet first.

I have some code that I have successfully posted JSON data to the API IF I hard code the JSON string, but I would like to set the results from a SQL query as an OBJ and then serialize them using NEWTONSOFT.JSON to pass to the API in place of the hard coded data.

public void Main()
        {

```
        string url = Dts.Variables["$Package::url"].Value.ToString();
        string user = Dts.Variables["$Package::user"].Value.ToString();
        string pwd = Dts.Variables["$Package::pwd"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString();



        string result = Dts.Variables["User::JSON"].Value.ToString();
        var JsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);


        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        string authHeader = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user + ":" + pwd));
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic" + " " + authHeader);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("Cookie: freedomIdentifyKey=XX");

         result.ToString();


        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(JsonResult);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();



            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();



            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result2 = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }



        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

I keep getting Error: 0x1 at Script Task: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Any thoughts on how I could resolve this?

Comment: First of I would use HttpClient to send JSON over HTTP. Could you maybe post the whole exception and which line is throwing the exception.

Comment: In order to do what Michael asked. Add a break point in your code and step through it. You will get a much better error message. But if I had to guess, I think it would be the serialization class has a null in it.

Comment: I added the full code above to show how I am sending the JSON package.  I also validated that there are no NULL values is the response. by running the query in SSMS. I am saving the full result set from my Execute SQL task and then adding that read only variable as an object in my script task......I may be missing something.

Comment: I added the break points and it seems to be in the stream writer, but I am just getting the same error with no more information.

Comment: You should check if there is an inner-exceptioon when debugging. The InvocationTargetException is just telling that something happened in a constructor.

Comment: I switched this over to run on SQL Server 2019 as the Deployment Target Version and my code runs perfectly. It seems there may be an issue with 'Downgrading' to that version some where in the setup. I have removed 2019 from my machine and installed 2017 but I am still getting the error. Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a `StreamWriter`.

```
string url = Dts.Variables["$Package::url"].Value.ToString();
string user = Dts.Variables["$Package::user"].Value.ToString();
string pwd = Dts.Variables["$Package::pwd"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString();
string result = Dts.Variables["User::JSON"].Value.ToString();

var JsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
string authHeader = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user + ":" + pwd));
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic" + " " + authHeader);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers.Add("Cookie: freedomIdentifyKey=XX");

using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(JsonResult);

    using (var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

And if you want to use HttpClient instead:

```
string url = Dts.Variables["$Package::url"].Value.ToString();
string user = Dts.Variables["$Package::user"].Value.ToString();
string pwd = Dts.Variables["$Package::pwd"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString();
string result = Dts.Variables["User::JSON"].Value.ToString();

// HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use. See Remarks.
var client = new HttpClient();

// Call asynchronous network methods in a try/catch block to handle exceptions.
try 
{
   var response = await client.PostAsync(url, result);
   response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
   string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
catch(HttpRequestException e)
{
   // do something
}
```

**Not tested**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this sorted out. The issue wasn't with the code, but rather with the Newtonsoft.JSON package. It was failing before it even got to the code and I was trying to run it as a SQL 2016 target. When I switched back to a 2019 project it ran fine. To get it to run as a 2016, I installed NEWTONSOFT.JSON using the GACUTIL and it runs great now.

I did make a change and used an SQL query in the code instead of using an execute SQL task and then passing it to a variable.